# Will silicone sealant not be waterproof after 14 hours?

Tags: shower, silicone

I had to silicone seal a small gap around bottom joint of our shower screen, where it is attached to the wall. We realised that a small but steady drip was soaking the floor over time. I sealed it fully about 7pm and it seemed 'set' following morning. So I used it, but still a small drip was magically seeping through.

So, could this be because after 14 hours it had not cured properly, or more likely I simply did a bad job? If it was because it was not properly cured, have I now ruined it? EIther way, can I simply plug in some more or should I start again?

Thanks for any advice guys.

Answer (score 2):

The silicone was probably cured enough to be used. The problem is probably either a poor bond due to surface contamination or a leak location you haven't found.

If you wish to re-caulk, peel and scrape the existing bead away and clean with alcohol.

Answer (score 1):

Is it old silicone? I've used bottles that were expired and they simply never 'cure'.